# Create table, and import data from csv or txt file

Tags: sql, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file that contains stock quotes. I am  new when it comes to SQL, but I have done a lot of research and come up with a code that I thought should work. But it doesn't. I get errors all the way....

```
USE ShakeOut 
GO
CREATE TABLE CSVTest1
(Ticker varchar(10),
dateval smalldatetime),
timevale time(),
Openval varchar(10),
Highval varchar(10),
Lowval varchar(10),
Closeval varchar(10),
Volume varchar(10),
)
GO

BULK
INSERT CSVTest1
FROM 'c:\TEST.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest1
GO
--Drop the table to clean up database.
DROP TABLE CSVTest1
GO
```

My CSV file has timevalue as 03:15:00 PM, and I'm not sure how to set that up in the table. The other values I think are aproxmately right, here's a sample of my csv file:

```
5/1/2009,9:30:00 AM,18.21,18.45,18.21,18.32,32163
5/1/2009,9:35:00 AM,18.33,18.34,18.27,18.29,36951
5/1/2009,9:40:00 AM,18.29,18.38,18.25,18.37,53198
5/1/2009,9:45:00 AM,18.38,18.4,18.28,18.285,49491
```

And here is my error messages in SQL Management Studio:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 208,
Level 16, State 82, Line 3 Invalid object name 'CSVTest1'. Msg 208,
Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid object name 'CSVTest1'. Msg 3701,
Level 11, State 5, Line 3 Cannot drop the table 'CSVTest1', because it
does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I would really appreciate help here, my head is about to explode after all these hours without any progression. I've tried MySQL too, didn't work there either.

As I'm  new, I might need it explained to the details.

Comment: The example CSV file does not quite match the table definition.  The table has a `Ticker` column, but the CSV example does not.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have an extraneous comma in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  There is a comma following the final column prior to the closing paren.  Perhaps it is valid in some implementations, but you might try removing it.  Change it to:

```
Volume varchar(10)
```

Ah - and it appears there is an extraneous closing parent in the second column definition. Change it to:

```
dateval smalldatetime,
```

And the time column:

```
timevale time,
```

Ultimately, it appears you should probably just try to get the CREATE TABLE statement syntax correct, then start adding the other parts.

Comment: Hi Mark I appreciate your help and suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't solve the case. I'm just lost here, spend to much time on VBA...

Comment: Thanks Mark, that was an good idea. I deleted the bulk section now, and the table is now working. But will it display the date when it comes to the AM/PM stuff?

Comment: @EspenSkeie: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. I believe the time should be imported correctly, but depending on your settings, I suppose it could end up being displayed in 24-hour format (rather than am/pm).

Comment: I got something out of this now, but I struggle with date and time... Can you see what I'm doint wrong, when I get this outputvalue: 2009-05-01 00:00:00 and for timevalue I get this: 10:20:00.0000000

Comment: See the example data in my answer.  When writing data for a date you should use yyyy-mm-dd eg: 2012-08-25 and time should use hh:mm:ss (24hr  clock is easiest) - and don't forget use colons not full stops eg: 22:15:00.

Comment: Yes Mark, I see that it switch to 24 hours, and that is fine for me. But how do I get rid of all those zeros at the end?

Comment: Hi Pete. The problem is that I download this stockqoutes from a site where they use 12 hour and AM/PM... I made this change, and it seems to work: time(0)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a comma after the last column definition: `Volume varchar(10),`.

I assume `timevale` should be `timeval`.

`time()` should just be `time`.

Also, I'm probably being picky but you have capitalised the first letter of all the column names except the first two - won't cause an error but probably better to have a consistent naming convention.  I would capitalise the 'v' in val and write the whole word too.

The CSV data needs revising too - you need to specify EVERY column, even if it is null.  See my example data (the new lines at the end of each row are for illustration purposes only).

```
1234567890,2012-08-25,22:15,anytext,ornum,for,varchar,columns <-new line
abcd123456,2010-05-20,00:01,anything,in,these,varchar,columns <-new line
abcd123456,2010-05-20,00:01,anything,in,,,columns             <-new line
```

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE CSVTest1 (
    Ticker varchar(10) NULL,
    DateValue smalldatetime NULL,
    TimeValue time NULL,
    OpenValue varchar(10) NULL,
    HighValue varchar(10) NULL,
    LowValue varchar(10) NULL,
    CloseValue varchar(10) NULL,
    Volume varchar(10) NULL)
GO

BULK INSERT CSVTest1
FROM 'C:\TEST.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO
```

Your CSV file needs to have a new line for each record you want to insert, as specified by the `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'` and a comma between each field as specified by `FIELDTERMINATOR = ','`.

EDIT:

By the way if you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) you can create the table through the user interface and then:

- Right click on the table
- Script Table as
- CREATE To
- New Query Editor Window

Comment: Thank you very much Pete. This was very helpful, and very quick response. I've tried some kind of an import/export function in SQL, but I will read up on those things this weekend. I started with SQL just a few days ago and have nothing but wholes in my knowledge! Thanks :-) espen

Comment: Here is a good tutorial for exporting query results to a CSV file: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/waterox-sql/2014/08/19/export-a-ssms-query-result-set-to-csv/